# How do I get the name of a file generated with a stream in C#?

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm building a Windows 8 metro app with XAML/C#. I'm saving an .xml file my data structure with a stream, like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObjectType));

using (var stream = await App.LocalStorage.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(MyObject.Title + ".xml", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName))
    serializer.Serialize(stream, MyObject);
```

Where:

```
App.LocalStorage
```

Is obviously a StorageFolder objecty set to

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

The GenerateUniqueName option is set in order to avoid collisions, because my objects can have the same title. Now, I need to get the file name my stream generated, how can I get it?

Thank you

Comment: did you already try debugging and checking all properties of the stream object? the concrete class and all available fields? I believe base stream or something like that should be there, had similar issue in the past.

Comment: What is MyObject and how is the MyObject.Title property set?

Answer (score 10):

Try creating the file first.

```
var sourceFileName = MyObject.Title + ".xml";
StorageFile storageFile = await App.LocalStorage.CreateFileAsync(sourceFileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, MyObject);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `OpenStreamForWriteAsync` method does not seem to give you any easy way to access this information. You could switch to accessing it another way:

```
StorageFile file = await App.LocalStorage.CreateFileAsync(...);
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    // do stuff, file name is at file.Name
```